# Counts on joined tables using Peewee

Tags: python, mysql, sql, join, peewee

I'm trying to write a query using the [Peewee ORM](http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). The query should return all names of Users which have at least one message associated with them. I currently try this as follows:

```
usersWithAtLeastOneMessage = User.select().where((fn.Count(User.messages) > 0)
for u in usersWithAtLeastOneMessage: 
    print u.name
```

in which my models look like this:

```
class User(db.Model):
    name = CharField()

class Message(db.Model):
    user = ForeignKeyField(User, related_name='messages')
    text = TextField()
```

This however, gives me the following error: `OperationalError: misuse of aggregate function Count()`.

I'm totally lost here though. Does anybody know how I can fix this? All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following statement, which should do what you're looking for.

```
User.select().where(fn.Exists(Message.select().where(Message.user == User.id)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter by aggregates, you need to

a) add a valid `group_by()` clause

b) do the filtering in a `having()` clause

like in

```
User.select().group_by(User).having((fn.Count(User.messages) > 0)
```